# Stability implies frequency response existance

Tags: control-theory

I was just wondering why when a system is stable there is a frequency response $\left(H(p) \rightarrow H(j\omega)\right)$ and when the system is unstable the frequency response doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1):

Both stable and unstable systems have a frequency response. So your statement is wrong.

When creating a bode plot, the difference is in the phase at the crossover frequency, that is to say the frequency at which the magnitude is equal to 0 decibel or gain of 1. A stable system will have a phase larger then -180 degrees, where a system which is unstable has a phase smaller then -180 degrees. This has to do with the stability criterium of Nyquist.

Comment: In my course it was stated that when the system is unstable the Lapace Transform region of convergence doesn't contain the imaginary axis and though the frequency response doesn't exist. But I don't understand this argument very well.